# Efficient Android resource override for regional users

Tags: android, android-studio, internationalization

I have an app originally written in UK English, hence all of the strings in `res/values/strings.xml` are in UK English.

I would like to provide a "translation" to US English. For the most part US and UK English are exactly the same, so in the US translation file I only want to specify those few string changes which are affected (about 10 of 120).

I have tried creating a `res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml` file (this name given by Android Studio) in which I've added only those 10 strings which differ. But Android Studio gives me errors in my main `strings.xml` for all the remaining strings: `"XXX" is not translated in "en" (English)`.

So, how can I efficiently provide translations to US English - ie specify only the 10 lines, without having to duplicate all the others? Duplication is always bad for code maintenance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `translatable="false"` settings to flag string resources that should not be translated. Something like:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">EasyApp</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="easy_app">I am a Simple App!</string>
    <string name="next_page">Next Page</string>
    <string name="second_page_message">I am the Second Page!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_second">SecondActivity</string>
</resources>
```

In the above sample, the app_name will not have to be translated in other locales. This way in the default strings.xml you can provide the UK version and mark with `translatable="false"` all the resources that you would like to maintain in US version to be the same. In `res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml` you will have to add only the messages that you need to maintain in US English.

Please note that if you are planning to use other locales/languages this method may not be the appropriate one, since this way you specify that the `translatable="false"` resources are the same for all locales.

You can check the [Configure untranslatable section](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor) rows if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I didn't know about that setting, so good to know. But I am likely to want to translate to other languages in future so unfortunately that won't work for me.